# Javascript ES6 reuse exports with callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback

Let's say I have 2 JavaScript files like the followings and they both import from **fileimport.js**(reusability)

The goal is, the **fileimport.js** has an event listener runs on each page. I want to call custom functions for each of the pages after the event runs.

**file1.js**

```
import * as fileimport from './fileimport';
...  

callback(){
   //run custom function
 }
```

**file2.js**

```
import * as fileimport from './fileimport';
...

 callback(){
   //run custom function
 }
```

**fileimport.js**
    ...

```
export ReusableFunc1(){
 ....
}

export ReusableFunc2(){
 ....
}

export Func3{
     form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) { callback })// I want to call callback() for each of the pages that import this.
}
```

I tried adding the **callback()** inside the fileimport.js and override in the regular pages but it did not work out(it did not call the regular pages function). How can I achieve something like this.

Comment: What do you mean, `it did not work out`? What was the error? What's the actual code you tried?

Comment: use self executing functions
(eventListener()
{
   callback();
})()

Comment: the error was callback() not found. Since it is not defined inside the fileimport. And I cannot define it there because it does now know what to do. I want to call back to the original js page to finalize the call.

Comment: If I define it inside the fileimport, it will call that, but it does not know what to do, since each page is customized

Comment: @MissakBoyajian have you solved your problem? If not, we can discuss it further. Otherwise, if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file `A.js` which provides code, that is used in `B.js` and `C.js`, than this file loaded and parsed **only once**. So a function call within `A.js` will be triggered only once, when the file is loaded.

If you want to call a function, provided by `A.js` whenever code from `A.js` is included somewhere, you cannot use an event listener, since there isn't any.

One thing you always can do is to trigger the desired function »manually« whenever you import `A.js`.

```
//A.js
const fx1 = () => {}
const fx2 = () => {}
const callback = () => {}

export { callback }
export default { fx1, fx1 }


//B.js

import { * as CodeFromA, callback } from 'A.js';

callback();
```

Another thing could be to change the export of `A.js` to something like:

```
export default () => {
  callback();
  return { ReusableFunc1, ReusableFunc2 }
}
```

This way you can:

```
 import CodeFromA from 'A.js'
 const ReusableFx = CodeFromA();
```

That would ensure that you get error if you try to use any of those `ReusableFunc*` without triggering the callback before.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. But I am still confused what you did. Inside A.js I have form submit listener like this. form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) { callback  }).
On click I wanna execute something in the custom page.

Did you answer two kinds of answers? or they are the same?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `callback` is not defined in fileimport.js. You would need *circular dependency* in order to achieve that, but I suggest you treat them with care, since, quoting [this relevant article](https://railsware.com/blog/2018/06/27/how-to-analyze-circular-dependencies-in-es6/) which I suggest you read:

> They are not always evil, but you might want to treat them with special care. They cause tight coupling of the mutually dependent modules. These kinds of modules are harder to understand and reuse as doing so might cause a ripple effect where a local change to one module has global effects.

If you don't need to call the `callback` function at import time, you shouldn't give you many problems though.

That being said, this would be the code to achieve what you want with a function:

**file1.js**

```
import * as fileimport from './fileimport';
...  

export function callback() {
   //run custom function
}
```

**fileimport.js**

```
import * as file1 from './file1';

ReusableFunc1(){
 ....
}

eventListener() {
   file1.callback();
}
```

As you can see, the problem remains if you have a lot of callback functions. If the number of functions you need to call increases, I suggest you change your code architecture not to have so much dependency from other modules.